# Dynamic dropdown for a webpage is not populating from my database

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

I cannot figure out why the dynamic dropdown won't populate from my database.:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Insert Album</h2>
<form action="insertalbum.php" method="POST">
Title: <input type="text" name="atitle" maxlength='50' required><br>
Band: <select name='bands'>
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("Server","database","password","username"); //i put in these placeholder for my actual credentials
// Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo nl2br("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n "); 
        }
   $query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM band";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                  unset($name);
        $name = $row['name']; 
                  echo '<option value="name"> $name </option>';

}
?> 
 </select>
<br>

Published Year: <input type="number" name="pyear" min='1900' max='2020' required><br>
Publisher: <input type="text" name="pname" maxlength='50' required><br>
Format:<select> <option value="record"> Record </option>
        <option value="cd"> CD </option>
        <option value="casette"> Casette </option>

</select> <br>
Price: <input type="number" name="price" min='0' max='9999.99'><br>
<input type="submit" value="Insert">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried checking how many rows there are in your result set (`$result->num_rows`)? Have you tried `print_r($row)` to see what one of those rows looks like, to confirm that the field name is what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

this a example:

```
<select id="employee">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select Employee Name</option>
<?php
/* connection */
$conn = mysqli_connect("Server","database","password","username");
/* query */
$sql = "SELECT id, employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age FROM employee LIMIT 10";
/* get data from db */
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
/* build your dropdown*/
while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $rows["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $rows["employee_name"]; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```